# Toasts not appearing when Pressing button? (Intents and ListView)

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.extraDetails);
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtra("details")){
        String extra = intent.getStringExtra("details");
        editText2.setText(extra);
    }
    else {
        editText2.setText(blank);
    }

    Button SaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveButton);
    SaveButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    intent.putExtra("details", editText2.getText());
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Item Details saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
```

The previous activity is a ListView, i have it set so that on click of a particular list item, it opens up a new instance of an activity, I'm trying to have it so a user can fill an EditText up with additional details which is then saved for when this particular item is clicked on in the future.

Code from setting up the Intent:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    IntentIndex="Intent"+position;
                    Intent IntentIndex = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(IntentIndex);
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Can you add your detail crash log trace?

Comment: `editText2.setText(blank);`. What is the value of blank ?

Comment: @john I declared it previously as ""

Comment: can you provide log trace ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to place `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)` before `final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.extraDetails);` in `onCreate` function.

Comment: Thanks, added that which prevents the app crashing!, however when pressing the button my toast does not appear and the string is not being put in to the Intents extras

Comment: Can you check whether `extra` is null?

Comment: Hi Jamie, maybe you can try `startActivityForResult` for your project.